# Azure CosmosDB geospatial query using MongoDB interface behave strangely

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, geospatial

I have a collection in Azure Cosmosdb (MongoDB API), which has a bunch of documents containing geospatial data. when I am querying the database for all points in a particular polygon, using MongoDB shell returns the points properly, but using pymongo gives me nothing. More specifically:

in mongodb shell

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> db.test_collection.find( { "Location" : { "$geoWithin" :  { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon" ,"coordinates" :[ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 41 , 0 ] , [41,6],[0,6], [0,0] ] ] }  } } } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e395a9929ae6f6ec66bc97e"), "info" : "test_info", "region" : "region", "Location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 40, 5 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e395ab895c1327b1c4568b4"), "info" : "test_info", "region" : "region", "Location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 40, 5 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e395b6bd76420859e134e26"), "info" : "test_info", "region" : "region", "Location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 40, 5 ] } }
```

The records are properly returned

in python (pymongo)

```
cur_collection = db.test_collection
points_in = cur_collection.find(
    { "Location" :
          { "$geoWithin" :
                { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon",
                            "coordinates" :
                                [ [
                                    [ 0 , 0 ] ,
                                    [ 41 ,0 ] ,
                                    [ 41 ,6 ],
                                    [ 0,  6],
                                    [ 0,  0]
                                ] ]

                }
            }
        }
    }
)
for point in points_in:
    print(point)
```

gives me nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?